# Webservice from WSDL using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat7, apache-axis, wsdl2code

I have a WSDL file and I would like to create a webservice from that using Java ("Contract first approach"). I used the WSImport-Tool from JAX-WS (Java version 1.6.0_07) on the command line to generate Java-code stubs. This worked fine and I received the following Java files:

```
Add.java
AddResponse.java
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
Test.java
TestPortType.java
```

But how do I go on from here?

I am using Eclipse. There I could set up a new "Dynamic Web Project" with Target Runtime = "Tomcat 7.0". In Configuration do I have to choose "Axis2"? (Tomcat 7 and Axis2 are already setup locally).

I am lost at this point and do not know how to keep going.

Does it make it easier to create the webservice using Axis2 or do you recommend using JAX-WS? Or is there an even better option?
How and where do I include my WSDL file so it gets deployed to Tomcat 7?